# Facebook app does not request permissions for mobile platform

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-center

I have two apps on facebook. I set for they same settings but they have different behavior for mobile platforms:

for url m.facebook.com/apps/{namespace}
- first app shows fb-page with request user permission (like this: https://m.facebook.com/apps/pandorama?fb_appcenter=1)
- second app does not show this page and redirects to my app domain.

Both apps have same settings and were not added to my fb account. Why they have different behavior? How I can setup my production app to show page with permissions?

https://m.facebook.com/apps/pandorama now redirects to domain, but works fine with parameter "fb_appcenter": m.facebook.com/apps/pandorama?fb_appcenter=1

test application works fine without fb_appcenter param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was fb bug. Now any apps redirect to domain regardless from parameters